# Match double slash in rails route constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

Suppose I am expecting a url as part of my route - maybe a callback url or similar - I might use the following route:

`get '/mymodel/:url', to: 'mycontroller#docallback', url: /.*/`

Now I would like to be able to go to `http://www.myapp.com/mymodel/http://www.google.co.uk/` and process `http://www.google.co.uk/` in mycontroller - but it is processed as `http:/www.google.co.uk/` (one slash). How can I rectify this? Is the regex wrong or is there some flag I have to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...Turned out that the request was not encoded on the client side before being sent, solution was to use `encodeURIComponent()` on the url before sending it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that "http://www.myapp.com/mymodel/http://www.google.co.uk/" is a valid url.

Normally if you want to pass a url as a parameter you would call `CGI.escape` on it first, which would convert `"http://www.google.co.uk/"` to `"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F"`  CGI.escape will turn any string into a url-safe version of itself, basically replacing any characters which have a special function in a url, like ":/?&" and also space and some other characters which would otherwise break the formatting.

So, you would end up with a url like

```
"http://www.myapp.com/mymodel/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F"
```

which would come through in params like

```
params = {:url => "http://www.google.co.uk/"}
```

Note how it's been unescaped here:  Rails automatically* calls `CGI.unescape` on parameter values before putting them into the `params` hash.

However, this url

```
"http://www.myapp.com/mymodel/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F"
```

looks pretty weird to me.  It would be better to be more explicit and pass it through as a named parameter in the url itself, like

```
"http://www.myapp.com/mymodel?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F"
```

which will require a slight change to your routes.

`*` I **think** Rails will do this but it might depend on circumstances.  Try it.

Comment: ...So as it stands, the url appears in params is `http:/google.co.uk`. Are you saying that calling CGI.escape on it will make it come through as `http://google.co.uk`?

Comment: I'm saying that calling CGI.escape on "http:/google.co.uk" will turn it into "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F" (btw, if it's in a form input, rails might do this automatically) which is a safe way to send it as a parameter.  At the other end, in the controller, Rails **might** automatically turn it back into "http:/google.co.uk", but if it doesn't, you can do it yourself with CGI.unescape

Comment: ....I've done as you've suggested and called `CGI.escp(params[:url])` but it's returning `http%3A%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F` instead of `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i misunderstood what you were saying, about the single slash.  Calling CGI.escape on a url with a missing forward slash will not magically add the extra slash back in.  Where are you getting the bad url from?  Ie "http:/google.co.uk"

Comment: It's strange because I can see that the server receives the url in the correct format -> `Started GET "/mycontroller/http://google.co.uk" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-06 14:20:17 +0100` but then rails logs this: `Parameters: {"url"=>"http:/google.co.uk"}` so what has happened between these logs that has corrupted the url?!

Comment: Are you sending through the escaped version?  Can you add your code for your form, or wherever the url is coming from, in an edit to your question please?

Comment: I just tried this `http://localhost:3000/admin?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F` and it came through as `Processing Admin::HomeController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-06 14:37:00) [GET] Parameters: {"url"=>"http://www.google.co.uk/"}`

Comment: ...Found the problem, the request is made from the client side via an ajax request. I needed to make the url safe in javascript before sending the request.

Comment: Ah, i see.  I guess you are using `encodeURIComponent()` in your javascript then?  Don't get this confused with `encodeURI()`, which will leave `"http://google.co.uk"` as is, since it IS a valid URI (but not a valid parameter)

Comment: yup you're absolutely right - I'm using `encodeURIComponent()`... Thanks for the heads-up :)